# Issue with installing angular compiler

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-compiler-cli

I have been spending hours trying to figure out what is wrong with trying to run an angular based project.
node version: v12.16.1

1. In my project directory I did npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.26
2. Once this was done, when I typed the command ng build --prod I got the error An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"
3. then I did npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
   there is something in the installation that mentions:

> "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0"
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.26 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0 but none was installed.
> npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.3.26 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0 but none was installed.

4. When I ran ng build --prod again, this time I got the error below instead:
   An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

What am I missing here? :(

Answer (score 0):

Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" This Npm package missing for you Computer , so plz Install

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: that is what I did in no 3. but it gave me another error in no 4. again

Comment: Sorry, i have attached 2 link , its solve your problem, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14185
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5095